Can I debug PHP with shared hosting?
I have VS Code installed on my client (laptop).
PHP is installed on the server. However, since its shared hosting, I can't install anything myself (like Xdebug). Is possible to debug PHP (set breakpoints, step through code)? For example, can I use the Interactive PHP Debugger?
NuSphere PhpED IDE says that the debugger works with shared hosting. I found a tutorial on how to set it up. I'm hoping the same can be done with VS Code.

you should never debug on a live server. Instead, configure a local development server on your laptop and use it to test and debug your code

You might be confusing development with production.
I've tried testing locally, and almost always the problem was the local environment was using different software and versions than the development environment.

I don't confuse anything. If you have issues with environment, then you have to recreate it using docker. Still debugging on a live server is not what you should be doing anyway.

In case you can add custom php.ini for you account, then technically it could be possible. But honestly, I I woudn't do it anyway, for the reason that debugger makes your php extremely slow alone.

I don't mind if the development environment is slow while debugging, because this wouldn't affect production.

remote === production. Otherwise there is zero sense in making it remote and torture yourself with problems like this

I don't think you can debug using phpdbg on a shared hosting as they usually have high security restrictions... Maybe you could ask them if they provide that service?
The only alternative solution I can think of is the "printf debug style", echoing messages through your app that can give you a hint of what may be going wrong. You can use a service like bcons for that (it has a free-forever plan).
Disclaimer: I'm one of the bcons developers, but this is no self promo, I've successfully used it to find bugs in environments like yours.

Given debugging on a live server should be a rare exception and by no means a rule, I don't find adding bells and whistles to the process necessary. An error log and tail -f in console would do in emergency. And when not in emergency, you should debug locally.
